# Ajax in JavaScript is posting raw data into web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, datatables, asp.net-ajax

When making an ajax request in JavaScript, it appears that the view has received a post of raw data into web page, i would say this is like looking at a csv file in notepad, just lines and lines of data, albeit the correct data, just not in the jquery datatable i would expect to see.

When just using Jquery to display all the data correctly in the table like so:

```
<script>
    $('#IndexTable').DataTable({ responsive: true });
</script>
```

There is no issue.

I have also tried this in the view:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        test();
    })

    var test = function () {

        $ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/ClinicalASSPATVM/test',
            success: function (response) {

                BindDataTable(response);


                }
            })
       }

    var BindDataTable = function (response) {

        $("#IndexTable").DataTable({


            "aadata": response,
            "aoColumn": [

                {"mData": "Product:"},
            ]

       });
    }
</script>
```

This is my Controller portion of the code:

```
        public ActionResult test(int? ClinicalAssetID)
        {

            var ClinicalASSPATVM = (from s in db.ClinicalAssets
                                    join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID into AP
                                    from subpat in AP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    orderby s.ClinicalAssetID descending

                                    select new ClinicalASSPATVM
                                    {
                                        ClinicalAssetID = s.ClinicalAssetID,
                                        ProductName = s.ProductName,
                                        ModelName = s.ModelName,
                                        SupplierName = s.SupplierName,
                                        ManufacturerName = s.ManufacturerName,
                                        SerialNo = s.SerialNo,
                                        PurchaseDate = s.PurchaseDate,
                                        PoNo = s.PoNo,
                                        Costing = s.Costing,
                                        TeamName = s.TeamName,
                                        StaffName = s.StaffName,
                                        InspectionDocumnets = subpat.InspectionDocumnets ?? String.Empty,
                                        InspectionOutcomeResult = subpat.InspectionOutcomeResult
                                    });


            return Json(new { data = ClinicalASSPATVM }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Assets.Areas.Clinical.Models.ClinicalASSPATVM>
<link href="~/content/datatables/media/css/datatables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/extensions/Responsive/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Clinical";
}

<div class="pageheader">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Clinical Asset Dashboard</h2>
    <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
        <span class="label">You are here:</span>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>Asset Management System</li>
            <li class="active">Clinical Assets - Overview</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>

     <div class="contentpanel">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                 <div class="panel-btns">
                     <a href="" class="minimize">&minus;</a>
                 </div><!-- panel-btns -->
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Last 10 Assets:</h3>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="table-responsive">
                     <table id="IndexTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                         <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>Product:</th>
                                 <th>Model:</th>
                                 <th>Supplier:</th>
                                 <th>Manufacturer:</th>
                                 <th>Serial No:</th>
                                 <th>Purchase Date:</th>
                                 <th>Purchase Order No:</th>
                                 <th>Cost:</th>
                                 <th>Team Location:</th>
                                 <th>Owner:</th>
                                 <th>Inspection OutcomeResult:</th>
                             </tr>
                         </thead>


                     </table>


                 </div><!-- table-responsive -->
             </div><!-- panel-body -->
         </div><!-- panel -->
     </div>



@section Scripts {


<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $ajax({
            url: '/ClinicalASSPATVM/test',
            method: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            sucess: function (data) {

                $('#IndexTable').datatable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "ProductName" },
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

This is the crazy output example, also i see no layout page headers, footers or side bars.

```
{"data": 
[{"ClinicalAssetID":75,"SerialNo":"34563463453453453","PurchaseDate":"\/Date(1551657600000)\/","PoNo":"567","Costing":1500,"InspectionDocumnets":"","ProductName":{"ProductID":2,"AssetAssignmentID":2,"ProductName":"Bed"},"InspectionOutcomeResult":null,"ModelName":{"ModelID":1,"AssetAssignmentID":2,"ProductID":8,"ModelName":"M1"},"Code":null,"AssetTypeName":null,"ManufacturerName":{"ManufacturerID":1,"AssetAssignmentID":2,"ProductID":8,"ManufacturerName":"Omron"},"StaffName":{"StaffID":1,"StaffName":
```

I Hope someone can shed some light on what i have done wrong.

Comment: what is the URL that produces the JSON data that you are seeing?

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass http://localhost:52679/Clinical/ClinicalAssets/test

Comment: that's the same URL you are calling to load data from `$ajax({ url: '/ClinicalASSPATVM/test'`. The ajax data need to go to one url, and your HTML + JS need to live at another URL.

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass sorry but that makes no sense to me. could you clarify.

Comment: your data needs a place to live. so you sent it to live at `/ClinicalASSPATVM/test`. that is the raw output you are seeing at that URL - it is JSON data. next, your view where the DataTable is needs a place to live. it needs to live in a second URL and then point to the first URL to gather data.

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass Right, Okay. I thought the /ClinicalASSPATVM/test was controller and view page and the JavaScript calling the data  through ajax was displayed on the view page. So effectively i should have two parts in the controller, some thing that gets the data and one for viewing the data?